# Run-time error '3075': syntax error in query expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a form on Access to filter a Subform based on the Column name "Control Type".

I am using a listbox to choose multiple values to filter with.

I also have a button that will execute the filter to the form.

I wrote this code:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strSearch As String
Dim Task As String

For Each varItem In Me!listControl.ItemsSelected
     strSearch = strSearch & "," & Me!listControl.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem

If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
     Task = "select * from tblAB"  
Else
     strSearch = Right(strSearch, Len(strSearch) - 1)
     Task = "select * from tblAB where Control_Type = '" & strSearch & "' "
End If
Me.tblAB_subform.Form.Filter = Task

Me.tblAB_subform.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

I am getting a Run=time error '3075' for the line:

```
Task = "select * from tblAB where Control_Type = '" & strSearch & "' "
```

Comment: I don't think that's the line that your code is stopping on.  I think you're *assuming* that's the line responsible, correct?  I say that because that line is not a *query expression*...yet.  So far it's a string, and wouldn't produce that error.

Comment: It could be **this** line giving that error: `Me.tblAB_subform.Form.Filter = Task`.  If so, add a line just before it: `Msgbox task`.  Is the SQL what you're expecting?

Comment: Not the cause of the error but strSearch ends up as "xxx,yyy,zzz" unless `Control_Type` actually contains the exact string "xxx,yyy,zzz" this wont work. If your intention is to match xxx or yyy or zzz you need to construct an IN() clause.

Comment: Carrying on from what @AlexK. commented you might be able to use `Task = "select * from tblAB where Control_Type IN ('" & Replace(strSearch, ",", "', '") & "')"` - I haven't tested so not willing to add as an answer, and it's more of Alexs thought pattern than mine. :)

Answer (score 3):

Run time error must not be on refered line.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-filter-property-access):

> The Filter property is a string expression consisting of a WHERE
>   clause without the WHERE keyword.

So is not a complete `SELECT` sentence, but just:

```
Task = "Control_Type = '" & strSearch & "'"
```